# Mac Pro stuck on white loading screen

Tags: macos, startup, mac-pro

I have Mac Pro which is running 10.8.5
After I turn on the Mac, I can see the regular apple logo, but after it's disappear, I see white screen (whiter than before) and a loading wheel for a few seconds, and it's disappear for 3-4 seconds and come back again.
And It's continue like that forever.
I suspect that start to happen after tried to attach my second monitor to my graphics card at the mini display port.

Things that I've tried so far:
**Safe Boot** - can't reach to it.
**Reset PRAM** - same results.
**Running** `fsck –fy` at **single-user mode** - same results.
**Repair Disk** - same results.
**Repair Permissions** - not clickable.
**Reinstall Mac OS X** - I get an error message "this item is temporarily unavailable"

Is there anything left for me to do?
I really hope that I won't have to reinstall everything from scratch, because I have a lot of stuff that I need on my SSD (the one which is running the OS X).

Comment: Try "Verbose Mode" - hold Command-V while booting and see if you can capture the output on a smartphone and paste it here.

Comment: @Allan What exactly do you want to see there?
All the text in there disappearing pretty quick, And there is sort of 1-2 different screen of it.

Comment: That will give us an idea of what is being loaded, what errors are being generated (if any) and what is happening prior to it crashing and rebooting.  If you have to, take a video and share it on DropBox or something similar.

Comment: @Allan here you go: https://www.dropbox.com/s/j0ol2jwq0lmax93/VID_20160305_140030.mp4?dl=0

Comment: I can't make any of the text out, but your computer ***is*** booting, it's just crashing on something.  Try running Apple Diagnostics - see:  https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201257 Can you update your post to include your Mac Model and year?

Comment: @Allan I've tried to press D and even command-D but I couldn't get to the AHT. My model number btw is A1289, but I can't remember the year.

Comment: That model was produced between 2009 and 2012, so you will be using AHT, not Apple Diagnostics.  I am assuming you have a CD/DVD Drive.  Do you have access to another machine to download and burn a copy of Ultimate Boot CD?  http://www.ultimatebootcd.com/  I have used that test to diagnose many Macs

Comment: @Allan I don't have a CD/DVD Drive at my machine.
But I think it can be implanted with USB drive.
What should I choose at the menu of this tool?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36572/discussion-between-hashirama-senju-and-allan).

Comment: Eventually, Succeeded to boot my Mac normally.
The bad news is that I run out of options, so I had to do the think I was most afraid of, *a restore*, and it cause me to lose 4 important days of work.

Answer (score 1):

How did you repair your disk? I did it through command line and it helped. This [topic](http://appletoolbox.com/2016/03/macbook-stuck-apple-logo-wont-boot/) might help.

Comment: Like I've said before, I already tried all of those options and it didn't work very well.